# is there a way to compare two strings without converting the Case?

Tags: javascript

I've searched enough but didn't find the solution, I want to get True for comparing these strings without converting them to lower case or uppercase. also if there is a solution if I use them as arrays, is accepted and ok for me.

```
const  string1 = "My dear friend"
var    string2 = "my dEar frienD"
```

Comment: `string1.localeCompare(string2)`, if it is true it will return 1 other wise -1 for false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`localCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which supports case insensitive comparisons.

```js
const  string1 = "My dear friend"
var    string2 = "my dEar frienD"

console.log(string1.localeCompare(string2, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0)
```